# How configure facebook app?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm not a very advanced user. Find Facebooks instructions very difficult or downright impossible.
I'm trying to make use of a plug-in with jQuery: http://ironlasso.com/jqueryfacebookwall-plugin/
The result can be viewed here: http://stella-polaris.nu/fb3.php

My problems are three:

1. The "Like" links (translated to "Gilla") are dead.
2. When writing something in the comment boxes and hitting Enter, nothing happens.
3. The word "undefined" in the sentence "undefined gillar det här" should be replaced with the number of Likes the post has. You might want to compare with the user's FB-page which I cannot link to (new and haven't enough "repuation" here). The username is "StellaPolarisKarlstad".

As far as I understand, the plug-in is OK and I have entered all relevant info to make it connect to the FB account and the app I have created. But I have obviously missed something when I made the app and have no idea what so ever what that might be.

Any suggestions?

Cheers,
Dan

Comment: Progress, but still not yet there.

I added the URL to the domain where the plug is located in the app settings and by that managed to make the comments work (item 2 in post above).

But still, item 1 and 3 above stays the same.

Please, somebody?

Cheers,
Dan

Comment: Problem solved.

Facebook had changed the way its Graph API returns some data (the Likes in this case) since the develop made the plug. His old Facebook app with the old code worked fine with the plug. My new Facebook app with the new code didn't.

So he mailed me a couple of snippets to replace existing code i a couple of files, and that did the trick.